# does a jquery plugin exist that would show a div then hide it after a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I remember writing this code in the past, so I could do it again, but I'm hoping to find a plugin that would do the same thing. Basically I have a div for error messages. At the start it's hdiden. When there's an error message, I show it, then fade it out after 20 seconds. Does a plugin already exist that could take div.class and the error message and do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$('div.class').show().delay(20000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `.delay()` and `.hide()` should do the trick. One thing to watch out for is that `hide()` with no arguments bypasses the event queue.

This page http://api.jquery.com/delay/ gives an example for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One way i prefer to use is:

```
$('#related_div').delay(20000).fadeOut(2500)
```

Which waits 20 seconds, then hides the div with a 2.5 second long fadeout effect...

Answer (score 1):

Wow a plugin for that ?

How about a simple settimeout :

```
$("#error").animate({"opacity":"100"};
setTimeout(function() {$("#error").animate({"opacity":"0"})} , 20 * 1000);
```